# How does "friendship" work for derived classes?

Tags: c++

There are three classes:

```
class A
{
    friend I_B;

    protected:

    void* mData;
};

class I_B
{
    void foo() = 0;
};

class B_Impl : public I_B
{

    B_Impl( A* value )
    :
    mData( value->mData ) <--- ERROR
    {

    }

    void foo() { mData->DoSomething() };

protected:

    void* mData;
};
```

At compile time I get an error in the constructor, that mData is a protected member.

Please explain me please why it happens.

Can I get access to protected members using "friendship" of the base class?

Comment: Friendship is not inherited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561648/why-does-c-not-allow-inherited-friendship

Comment: `B_Immpl` is not even derived from `I_B`.  Was it supposed to be?

Comment: Simply put: Your mother's friends are not necessarily your friends too! :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Friendship is not inherited. If you want `B_Impl` to be a friend of `A` you must declare `B_Impl` as a friend.

Friendship is also not transitive: your friend's friend is not necessarily your friend.

Comment: A nice link too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561648/why-does-c-not-allow-inherited-friendship

Comment: Thanks, of course if i use friendship between A and B_Impl all works fine. But the design of the application do not allow to do this. So I will create accessor methods to get particular data. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Sergey K, thanks for the link