# Child class inherit friendship

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, access-control

I have a class State and another friend class Game. My question is, if I have a class MenuState which extends State, is MenuState a friend of Game as well?

EDIT:

So if I have a situation like this:

```
class Game
{
    private:
        StateManager* myStateManager = new StateManager();
}

class State
{
    public:
        static void create(StateManager* Parent, const std::string name) {};

    private:
        StateManager* parent;
}

#define DECLARE_STATE_CLASS(T)                                   \
static void create(StateManager* Parent, const std::string name) \
{                                                                \
        T* myState = new T();                                    \
        myState->parent = Parent;                                \
        Parent->manageState(name, myState);                      \
}                                                                \

class MenuState : State
{
    public:
        DECLARE_STATE_CLASS(MenuState)
}

int main()
{
    Game app;
    MenuState::create(This needs to be the stateManager in app, "MenuState");
    app.init("MenuState");
}
```

How can I make this work without making the state manager public?

Comment: No , check the following, friendship won't be inherited.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561648/why-does-c-not-allow-inherited-friendship

Comment: Please see the original question.

Answer (score 1):

So if the situation is like the following

```
class Game {
  friend class State;
}

class State {

}

class MenuState : public State {

}
```

Then the answer is no, as `friend` directive is not implicitly inherited. And I don't see why it should be inherited, `Game` explicitly allows `State` to access its internal implementation details but why this should be extended to subclasses of `State` which could do different things?

Comment: Alright, I have an object (declared private StateManager* myStateManager = new StateManager(); in Game) that I want MenuState to be able to access because I pass myStateManager to the MenuState::Create(StateManager* Parent, const std::string stateName) function. Without making myStateManager public, is this possible?

Comment: I apologize for that. That was really confusing, not very good at formatting text in comments. If you don't quite understand what I mean or want me to post the exact code I'll edit the OP.

Comment: Please see the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an access function to Game. Even if MenuState is a friend of Game, this still won't work, since you are trying to pass Game's private member, not access it inside the function.

If for instance, you have no right to modify Game, then the choice would be to add an access function inside State, and then you can use that access function from MenuState.

```
class State
{
    public:
    static void create(StateManager* Parent, const std::string name) {};
    StateManager* getManager(Game* g){
        return g->myStateManager;
    }

    private:
    StateManager* parent;
}

#define DECLARE_STATE_CLASS(T)                                   \
static void create(Game* g, const std::string name) \
{                                                                \
        T* myState = new T();                                    \
        myState->parent = State::getManager(g);                              \
        Parent->manageState(name, myState);                      \
}                                                                \
```