# Unable to access members of including class from a polymorphic nested classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, inner-classes

A nested class `Foo::Utility` has access to another nested class `Foo::Container` even if the later is private. I am trying to extend this access to a polymorphic version `UtilityPrint` of `Foo::Utility` without success:

```c
class Foo {
private:
  class Container {};

public:
  class Utility {
  public:
    virtual void action(Container &) = 0;
    // works even if Container is private
  };

  Container container;
  Utility * utility;

  Foo(Utility * utility): container(), utility(utility) {};

  void performAction() {
    utility -> action(container);
  }
};

// polymorphic nested class
// failed attempt
class UtilityPrint : Foo::Utility {
public:
  virtual void action(Foo::Container &) {
    /* Implementation */

    // this does not work, because Foo::Container is private
  }
};
```

Is there a correct way to achieve this, or is this a bad idea to begin with?

The error message I get is this:

```
error: ‘class Foo::Container’ is private
   class Container {};
         ^
error: within this context
   virtual void action(Foo::Container &) {
```

Also, Here is my reason for using this somewhat weird design:
I wanted a `container` and a polymorphic `utility` that does things to both the container and `Foo`. Since both `container` and `utility` would only be used within the context of `Foo`, I put the two classes into `Foo`.

---

EDIT: I can wrap the derived `Utility` in a derived `Foo`, and the code compiles:

```c
class Foo {
protected:
  class Container {};

public:
  class Utility {
  public:
    virtual void action(Container &) = 0;
  };

  Container container;
  Utility * utility;

  Foo(Utility * utility): container(), utility(utility) {};

  void performAction() {
    utility -> action(container);
  }
};

class FooPrint : public Foo {

public:
  class Utility : Foo::Utility {
  public:
    virtual void action(Foo::Container &) {
      /* Implementation */
    }
  };

};
```

This however introduces a wrapper class `FooPrint` which exists only for syntactic reasons and is (being a derived class!) never meant to be instantiated. I don't like this approach for this reason, but I can be very wrong on this regard.

Comment: I would rather put them as standalone classes in the same namespace (especially if they are used as base classes), but that is just my opinion. If you want to keep your design, your only choice is to make `Foo::Container` a public type aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adopted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416231/c-allow-derived-classes-of-friend-to-have-access-to-private-nested-class?rq=1):

```c
class Foo {
protected:
  class Container {};

public:
  class Utility {
  protected:
    typedef Container FooContainer;

  public:
    virtual void action(Container &) = 0;
  };

  Container container;
  Utility * utility;

  Foo(Utility * utility): container(), utility(utility) {};

  void performAction() {
    utility -> action(container);
  }
};

class UtilityPrint : Foo::Utility {
public:
  virtual void action(FooContainer &) {
    /* implementation */
  }
};
```

When the name `FooContainer` is introduced using `typedef`, accessibility is applied to that name only, with no regard of it actually referring to `Foo::Container`. This allows all derived `Utility` to reference `Foo::Container` by naming `FooContainer`.

I believe this also applies to `using`

Answer (score 1):

**Access is not inherited.** This is more often brought up when discussing [friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Notes), but it applies here as well.

First, let's look at why `Foo::Utility::action` can access the private class `Foo::Container`. Actually, it's right there in the names. The `Foo::Container` can only be accessed by members of `Foo`, and members of `Foo` can be recognized when you write out their qualified names and that name starts with "`Foo::`".

In contrast, `UtilityPrint` is not a member of `Foo`. (In fact, it would be a huge security violation if someone could simply say *"oh, yeah, I'm a member too!"* and get access to your private information.) So while `UtilityPrint` has (protected) access to `Foo::Utility`, it does not have access to everything to which `Foo::Utility` has access.

If `Foo::Utility` desires to extend its access to classes derived from it, it would need to explicitly do so. One way to do this is by creating an alias.

```
class Utility {
  protected:
    using Container = Foo::Container;  // Derived classes can access this.
  public:
    virtual void action(Container &) = 0;
    virtual ~Utility() {}  // <-- remember to properly support polymorphism 
};
```

That still leaves open the question of whether or not this is good design. I would consider this a warning flag that something might be off, but not conclusively so. The question does not have enough context for me to make this sort of call. I would just give you the guideline that if you feel like you are circumventing a lot of language features (like private access), then maybe the design needs work.

Comment: Here is the context of my design: `Foo::Container` is a data structure that is part of the `Foo` implementation, so I made it a private nested class to encapsulate it. And I need some polymorphic utilities that does things to `Container`, but I don't know how to grant access of `Container` to only `Utility` and its offspring without making it public.

Comment: I have more than one `utility`s, so making `Foo` polymorphic instead would lead to a lot of diamonds. For the same reason I cant make `Container` nested in `Utility`.

Comment: @YifanLai That is information about your current design, not the context of the design. The context I referred to would focus more on what you are trying to accomplish than on how. A comment is probably not long enough to give the necessary context.