# How can I remove/refactor a «friend» dependency declaration properly?

Tags: c++, refactoring, friend

The background of this question is based on a practical sample where I wanted to remove a «friend» dependency from a pair of classes that are used to manage read/write locked access to a shared resource.

Here's an abstraction of the original structural design for that scenario:

[image: Original Design using friend]

Marked in red, there's this ugly «friend» dependency I want to remove from the design.

In short, why do I have this thing there:

1. `ClassAProvider` shares a reference to a `ClassA` over a number of
   concurrently accessing `Client` instances
2. `Client` instances should access `ClassA` solely through the `ClassAAccessor` helper class
   that manages the internals
3. `ClassA` hides all methods intended to be used from `ClassAAccessor` as protected.
4. So `ClassA` can ensure that `Client` needs to use a `ClassAAccessor` instance

This pattern comes primarily useful, when it's about ensuring to leave instances of `ClassA` in a
defined state, if a `Client` operation bails out (because of e.g. an uncaught exception). Think of
`ClassA` providing (internally visible) paired operations like `lock()`/`unlock()` or `open()`/`close()`.

The (state-)reversing operations should be called in any case, especially when a client crashes due
to an exception.
This can be safely handled through the `ClassAAcessor`'s life cycle behavior, the destructor
implementation can ensure it.
The following sequence diagram illustrates what's the intended behavior:

[image: The desired behavior of the overall construct]

Additionally `Client` instances can achieve a fine control of accessing `ClassA` easily, just using
C++ scope blocks:

```
// ...
{ 
    ClassAAccessor acc(provider.getClassA());
    acc.lock();
    // do something exception prone ...
} // safely unlock() ClassA
// ...
```

All fine so far, but the «friend» dependency between `ClassA` and `ClassAAccessor` should be removed for a number of good reasons

1. In the UML 2.2 Superstructure, Section C.2 under Changes from previous UML it says: *`The following table lists predefined standard elements for UML 1.x that are now obsolete. ... «friend» ...`*
2. Most coding rules and guidelines I've seen forbid, or strongly discourage using friend, to avoid the tight dependency from the exporting classes to the friends. This thing brings in some serious maintenance issues.

As my question title says

**How can I remove/refactor a friend declaration properly (preferably starting out at the UML design for my classes)?**

Comment: completely off-topic but which uml tool did you use?

Comment: I have setup this Q&A motivated by this question: [C++ OOP Only grant access to certain classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487362/c-oop-only-grant-access-to-certain-classes). That's the essence how to refactor a friend relationship, that I once wrote up in an article, and now provided as a Q&A here.

Comment: @midor [tag:enterprise-architect] originally. The diagram images posted here are screenshots from a PDF I have actually.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Don't try to force your code to the latest UML changes. UML is a good tool, but, it was originally designed "too tied" to Java, and eventually more flexible for other P.L. (s) . Some features of UML, either new or deprecated, are very conceptual to be applied to source code. "Friend" ("Package" in Java) is useful feature, maybe should be "retagged" in UML, but is not wrong to use it.

Comment: @umlcat _"Don't try to force your code to the latest UML changes."_ I'm not doing so actually. My concerns are about c++ design primarily. The _friend_ relationship was discouraged in c++ designs  (for the mentioned reasons) long before UML declared it obsolete. My point about using UML, is just to point out which changes need to be done in a particular order (or scheme) from a structural POV.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I ignore `friend` access was discouraged in C++, but, for me is a good feature, than can be applied well or bad. It's supported in several P.L., maybe with different syntax (Java, Object Pascal, Visual Basic, ...), maybe `interface` access could be a suitable replacement

Comment: @umlcat Though this question is about c++ actually :-P ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's setup some constraints for refactoring first:

1. The ClassAAccessor's publicly visible interface should change in no way
2. The ClassA internal operations should not be visible/accessible from the public
3. The overall performance and footprint of the original design should not be hurt

---

**Step 1: Introduce an abstract interface**

For a first shot, I factored out the «friend» stereotype, and replaced it with a class (interface)
`InternalInterface` and the appropriate relations.

[image: 1st shot refactoring]

What made up the «friend» dependency, was split up into a simple dependency relation (blue) and
a «call» dependency (green) against the new `InternalInterface` element.

---

**Step 2: Move the operations, that make up the «call» dependency to the interface**

The next step is to mature the «call» dependency. To do this, I change the diagram as follows:

[image: Matured design]

- The «call» dependency turned into a directed association from
  `ClassAAccessor` to the `InternalInterface` (I.e. `ClassAAccessor` contains
  a private variable `internalInterfaceRef`).
- The operations in question were moved from `ClassA` to `InternalInterface`.
- `InternalInterface` is extended with a protected constructor, that it's useful in inheritance
  only.
- `ClassA`'s «generalization» association to `InternalInterface` is marked as `protected`,
  so it's made publicly invisible.

---

**Step 3: Glue everything together in the implementation**

In the final step, we need to model a way how `ClassAAccessor` can get a reference to `InternalInterface`. Since the generalization isn't visible publicly, `ClassAAcessor` can't initialize it from the `ClassA` reference passed in the constructor anymore. But `ClassA` can access `InternalInterface`, and pass a reference using an extra method `setInternalInterfaceRef()` introduced in `ClassAAcessor`:

[image: Glue everything together]

---

Here's the C++ implementation:

```
class ClassAAccessor {
public:
    ClassAAccessor(ClassA& classA);
    void setInternalInterfaceRef(InternalInterface & newValue) {
        internalInterfaceRef = &newValue;
    }
private:  
    InternalInterface* internalInterfaceRef;
};
```

This one is actually called, when the also newly introduced method `ClassA::attachAccessor()`
method is called:

```
class ClassA : protected InternalInterface {
public:
    // ...
    attachAccessor(ClassAAccessor & accessor);
    // ...
};

ClassA::attachAccessor(ClassAAccessor & accessor) {
    accessor.setInternalInterfaceRef(*this); // The internal interface can be handed
                                             // out here only, since it's inherited 
                                             // in the protected scope.
}
```

Thus the constructor of ClassAAccessor can be rewritten in the following way:

```
ClassAAccessor::ClassAAccessor(ClassA& classA)
: internalInterfaceRef(0) {
    classA.attachAccessor(*this);
}
```

---

Finally you can decouple the implementations even more, by introducing another `InternalClientInterface` like this:

[image]

---

It's at least necessary to mention that this approach has some disadvantages vs using `friend` declarations:

1. It's complicating the code more
2. `friend` doesn't need to introduce abstract interfaces (that may affect the footprint, so constraint 3. isn't fully fulfilled)
3. The `protected` generalization relationsip isn't well supported by the UML representation (I had to use that constraint)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency say nothing about accessing of attributes or operations. Dependency is used to represent definition dependency between model elements !
What about to remove all dependencies from your model and learn how to use visibility.
If your friend relationship represents accessing of feature (attribute or operation) from specific type (class), you can set visibility of attribute or operation to Package.  Package visibility means, that attribute value is accessible from instances which classes are defined in the same package.

Define ClassAProvider and Client in same package and set classA attribute visibility to Package visibility type. Client instance can read classA attribute value, but instances of other types not defined in the same package cannot.

Comment: There's no such thing like _package visibility_ (by means of namespaces) available for [tag:c++] (compared to [tag:c#] or other languages). Your proposal is welcome but doesn't help for my actual case, that is concsiously bound to c++ solutions.

Comment: Ok , but visibility of package type in UML is equivalent to friend declaration i C++

Comment: Well, `friend` may be a correct implementation of package visibility, and the current language standard supports this better regarding inline definition support of free standing `friend` functions from the namespace. For classes though, that introduces that _maintenance nightmare_ I've mentioned in my question (see reason 2.). When I'm sure what I'm doing, and can be pretty sure the maintenance issue is unlikely to arise, I also well ignore that «friend» relationships are obsolete in UML. I just wanted to show a way how it can be refactored in a proper, equivalent (by access policies) way.