# Pure Virtual Friend Class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, friend, pure-virtual

I have class `A` that has a pointer to an instance of the pure virtual class `B`. Class `C` is derived from `B` and will automatically have a pointer to `A` (which is its parent), and needs to access its members. This can be achieved by adding `friend class C` inside class `A`, though then this is needed for every class that will derive from `B`.

Code example:

```
class A
{
public:
    friend class B; // This does not allow derived classes to be friends
    friend class C; // Now derived class B has access to `DoDomething`, but then this is needed for every single derived class

private:
    void DoDomething();
};


class B
{
    virtual void Tick() = 0;

protected:
    A* m_pointerToA; // <- is being set upon creating automatically
};


class C : public class B
{
    virtual void Tick()
    {
        m_pointerToA->DoSomething();
    }
};
```

Is there a way to make all derived classes from `B` have access to private and protected members of class `A` that they are pointing to, without having to add `friend class X` for each of them?

Comment: `friend`ing isn't derived, you can't.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then I'm stuck with having to either make `A`'s members and methods public, or befriending every derived class I assume?

Comment: @Broxzier No you are not, because `B` can expose the functionality that needs friendship to its derived classes through protected member functions of its own.

Comment: @Broxzier I've provided a "little" workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly) how to get rid of friend relationships and replace them with interfaces.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's very interesting, I'll definitely give abstract interfaces a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since friendship is not inherited, you need to wrap all the functionality that relies on friendship into protected functions of the base class `B`. This will let all classes deriving from `B` access the functionality of `A` that needs "befriending":

```
class B {
    virtual void Tick() = 0;
protected:
    A* m_pointerToA; // <- is being set upon creating automatically
    void callDoSomething() {
        m_pointerToA->DoSomething();
    }
};


class C : public class B {
    virtual void Tick() {
        std::cout << "Class C is about to tick..." << std::endl;
        callDoSomething();
    }
};

class D : public class B {
    virtual void Tick() {
        callDoSomething();
        std::cout << "Class D has just ticked!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This effectively localizes the area where the friendship is used in your class hierarchy to class `B`, which helps with encapsulation.