# How make a class private inside a namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, private

How make a class private inside a namespace in C++ and prevent other to access the class from outside the namespace, for instance:

```
namespace company{
    class MyPublicClass{ ... }  // This should be accessible 
    class MyPrivateClass{ ... } // This should NOT be accessible
}
```

Comment: Put it in a private header file?

Comment: I think namespaces can't do that. Maybe what you want are C++ modules. Or just use nested classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have access specifiers for namespaces, but you can for *classes*:

```
class company {
    // Private (default)
    class MyPrivateClass { ... };

public:
    class MyPublicClass { ... };
};
```

You access the classes just like for a namespace with the scope operator:

```
company::MyPublicClass my_public_object;
```

If the "public" class should have access to the "private" class, then the "private" class have to be a `friend` of the `public"  class.

---

There is also another way, and that is to simply not have the `MyPrivateClass` definition in a public header file. Either define the class in the source file, or in a private header file only included internally.

Which way to choose depends on your design and use-cases.

Comment: The falls apart if you want to add to the namespace elsewhere. Since you cannot "merge" multiple class definitions, in the same way that multiple namespace definitions combine,

Comment: @nate If you're wanting to make a class private to a namespace chances are the intent is to limit its use so stuffing it into a class definition is probably not going to have a significant impact on usability (outside the scope of the intent here).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  That is quite possible, I just was pointing out a potential pitfall of this approach. I have taken this approach in the past to allow me to specialize templates on a "namespace".

Answer (score 12):

You can use `unnamed namespace`. Names that appear in an unnamed namespace have internal linkage but names that appear in a named namespace and don't have any storage class specifier, by default, have external linkage.

For example we have a file named `source1.cpp`:

```
//source1.cpp
namespace company{
    class MyPublicClass{ ... };
    namespace{
        class MyPrivateClass{ ... };
    }
}
void f1(){
company::MyPrivateClass m;
}
```

`MyPublicClass` has external linkage and `MyPrivateClass` has internal linkage. So there is no problem with `source1` and it can be compiled as a library ,but if we have other file named `source2.cpp`:

```
//source2.cpp
void f2(){
company::MyPrivateClass m;
}
```

`source2` can't be linked with the compiled `source1` and we can not refer to `MyPrivateClass`.

Comment: Had a problem with duplicate class and method names in multiple modules (Classes in each module with same name and same method but not declared in header, so no external visibility; Linker silently drops all but one implementation) and your tip solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Does not work for template classes, because you should put them in header files.

Comment: @Somnium explicit instantiation declaration and definition are useful for such cases.

Comment: Yes, in some cases it is good solution, however, when writing a general purpose library then it's not possible to use explicit instantiation. In such case namespace named like `internal` could be used (like other answer suggests).

Comment: @Somnium The original header can be included in a second header where you place the explicit instantiation declaration. You can then use the second header in your project.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot.

C++ namespaces don't provide any scoped accessors, neither do class declarations (vs C# for example).

The usual way is to introduce an `internal` namespace to indicate `public` usage isn't intended.

You may restrict  access using `friend` specifiers.

You can also use some tricks, to make it harder accessing an interface publicly like explained here: [How can I remove/refactor a «friend» dependency declaration properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly)