# Only let the specific class 'Fabric' construct instances of class 'Foo' and all of its subclasses

Tags: c++

Is there a way to ensure that only class `Fabric` can construct the class `Foo` and all of its sub-classes, without having to declare a private constructor and `friend class Fabric` in each sub-class?

```
struct Foo {
   friend class Fabric;
protected:
   Foo() = default;
};

struct FooConcrete1 : Foo {
   friend class Fabric;
protected:
   Foo() = default;
};
```

Since friendship is not inherited, both manual actions when declaring each sub-class seem to be needed, which is error-prone.

Comment: May be restrict `Foo`'s constructor to take a reference to `Fabric` as constructor parameter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Hmm, clever! That makes the compiler ensure the construction rules, but still requires manual labor in each sub-class.

Comment: That won't forbid subclasses of `Fabric` to construct any `Foo` instances tho :-/

Comment: Why do you need it? It's seems like an X-Y problem..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that's not a requirement.

Comment: @KorelK: this is exactly the problem. I have two sub-classes for which I need to ensure this rule, possibly more in the future, and I'm looking for the best way to express this intent with code in such a way that's enforced by the compiler, and also requires the least duplication in each of the sub-classes. There's no X.

Comment: Hmm, well. Someone could still create a `Fabric` instance, and use that to construct subclasses of `Foo`. I didn't think that through to the end. I once wrote  a [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly) how to remove `friend` relationships properly. I believe that describes that pattern better.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: you're right, but that's also not a requirement. I'm trying to defend against human error in my own code, not against malicious intent in some library intended for wide use.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Post an answer if you don't have any more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to declare a tag structure which is only constructible by `Fabric` and pass this object to the constructor of `Foo`. If you forget to add the constructor to derived classes you will get an error that `Foo` isn't default constructible.

```
struct FooTag
{
    friend struct Fabric;
private:
    FooTag();
};

struct Foo {
    Foo(FooTag tag) {}
};

struct FooConcrete1 : Foo {
    using Foo::Foo;
};

struct Fabric
{
    void test()
    {
        FooConcrete1 f = FooConcrete1(FooTag());
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooConcrete1 f; // can't construct as we can't construct FooTag
    return 0;
}
```