# Two classes with same, standalone, hidden functionality

Tags: c++

There is **one** file with two separate classes and one function:

```
int foo(int x) {return x+x;}
class A {
    public:
    int bar(){return foo(0);} 
};
class B {
    public:
    int bar(){return foo(1);}
};
```

and they both need to use function

which uses only its argument (not use any data from A or B).
I can declare this function as global. But i would like to hide this function for other files (so this is un visible, unacccesible in other files). So i can declare this function as member function of each class A and B. But this will be code duplicate.

What is the best practice for that?

Comment: have you considered to implement this method in a base class and to make it protected and the two classes should implement this base class?

Comment: You want to "hide" it, in what sense? Do you want to prevent accidentally using it? Or are you trying to make sure that it's completely inaccessible?

Comment: I like the idea of @BudaGavril and I'm waiting for him to answer.

Comment: unvisible in other files, so there would not exist

Comment: You question does not specify whether the function must have private/protected and/or friended access to `A` and/or `B` members. If not, did you consider an anonymous namespace?

Comment: Is there also one file that holds the implementations of `A` and `B`? Do you use this function in any inline member of `A` and `B`? You can't just slap `...` in your example and assume such information is not important.

Comment: @WhozCraig The OP states *"they both need to use function which uses only its argument (not use any data from A or B)"*, so I guess you might expand that comment in an answer...

Comment: @pi.314 Regarding a wider view for maintenance and reusing implementation details, why are you trying to hide these as rigorously claimed for the function foo(). Why do you need to hide this implementation detail at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just omit any declarations of `foo` from any headers, and [mark it `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function) or define it in an anonymous namespace.

AB.h

```
class A { int bar(); };
class B { int baz(); };
```

AB.cpp

```
static int foo(int x) { return x+x; }
/* or
namespace {
    int foo(int x) { return x+x; }
}
*/    


int A::bar() { return foo(1); }
int B::baz() { return foo(2); }
```

Comment: As i look it now i see it so obvious.. Thanks!

Comment: But then you have to implement the function everywhere you use one of the classes. That would be code duplication

Comment: @ThomasSablik If you start needing it elsewhere, then why **must** it be hidden? At that point you can just remove `static`

Comment: So, hiding was really the goal. You didn't need to *protect* access.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - Wut? We build object files (from cpp files) and then link them. No duplication.

Comment: Ok, now I got it.

Comment: @pi.314 Making functions private by using `static` linkage is probably not the best solution.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ perhaps it's a really commonly named function, and pi doesn't want to pollute the global namespace

Comment: @Caleth That's why I suggested using another namespace, as a way to separate it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Hiding pure implementation details by not even having them in a header is not probably, but definitely the best solution. Something that should be done by default whenever the opportunity arises.

Comment: @StoryTeller Maintenance horror tho whenever you want to reuse that functionality with a new implementation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Because we'll need to edit this *one file* to make use of the now exposed interface? The horror!

Comment: @StoryTeller I beleve what I proposed in my answer (the link) is more generic. There's probably need to check how to use static polymorphism to get rid of the virtual interfaces overhead. The need to have all implementations in a single translation unit, since they share a common implementation detail is probably a not so good idea maintenance wise. Before doing that I'd even prefer `friend`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply place the function inside another class that only exists in that file:

```
class C
{
public:
    static void foo(int) {}
};

class A
{
    void test1()
    {
        C::foo(0);
    }
};

class B
{
    void test2()
    {
        C::foo(0);
    }
};
```

A & B can access this function now and it's not being declared globally.

You can also put the function in its own namespace:

```
namespace ABFunctions
{
    void foo(int) {}
}
```

And that is another way of keeping it separated, logically.

If you need to *protect* access, you can do it this way:

```
class C
{
friend class A;
friend class B;
private:
    static void foo(int) {}
};

class A : C
{
    void test1()
    {
        C::foo(0);
    }
};

class B : C
{
    void test2()
    {
        C::foo(0);
    }
};
```

Now, only class A & B will have access to `foo(int)`.

Comment: So can any outside code access this function. What's stopping others from calling `C::foo`?

Comment: Is that imperative? I'm not clear if the object is to "hide" it or actually prevent access.

Comment: "Hiding completely" (like the OP seems intent on) is the ultimate form of preventing access. So it's best to address that.

Comment: Fair enough. The third method will prevent access.

Comment: The last solution is useful when `foo` needs to be used in an inline function (in a header). A possibility the OP didn't clarify about, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base class and derive from it. You won't have to duplicate code.

```
class Base {
    virtual ~Base = 0;
protected:
    int foo(int x) {return x+x;}
};

class A : public Base {...}
class B : public Base {...}
```

You can't instantiate an object of `Base`.

Comment: So an artificial base class, and the overhead of virtual functions just to share some functionality? This is C++ OOP gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not use any data from A or B, then it probably shouldn't be implemented within A or B. It sounds as if f was some kind of auxiliary function. Perhaps creating a class `Utilities` and making it a public static function of the utilities class would be better.

Comment: If he would do it global, than he can't hide it from another classes.

Comment: A `Utilites` class usually is an anti pattern as it contains many different methods and properties that don't belong together.

Comment: Perhaps I got the question wrong. It is indeed unclear what "hiding" means. If usage should be prevented, then the utilities class could be a private nested class or it could have private static methods and declare A and B as friends.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ there's no *hiding* of functions at namespace level, though you can create a utility class that contains only private static functions, and explicitly specify which classes may have access using the `friend` keyword:

```
class C {
   friend class A;
   friend class B;
   static void foo(int);
};

int foo(int x) {return x+x;}
class A {
    public:
    int bar(){return C::foo(0);} 
};
class B {
    public:
    int bar(){return C::foo(1);}
};
```

Though that's not a very good design pattern, since `friend` introduces some more maintenance effort, as soon other classes than `A` or `B` need to access `foo` as well.

A probably better pattern is to use an interface as I've sketched out in my Q&A here:

- [How can I remove/refactor a «friend» dependency declaration properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly)

The introduction of interfaces there suffers from the overhead of `virtual` polymorphism though. Maybe that could be resolved with introduction of [static polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) via the CRTP.

---

Regarding a wider view for maintenance and reusing implementation details, why are you trying to hide these as rigorously claimed for the function `foo()`. Why do you need to hide this implementation detail at all?

Comment: This is in my suggestion as well but I used `static` for `foo(int)`. I don't think there's a need to force an instantiation of the "extra" class.

Comment: @D.Go Oops, I forgot to put the `static` keyword. Tho, I believe my way laid out in the linked Q&A is the better way to go.