# How to check class friendship?

Tags: c++, friend, type-traits

The standard library provides many useful "is" typetraits that tell about the relationship of two classes, such as `is_base_of`, `is_convertible`, `is_same`, etc. Is there any way to implement a typetrait `is_friend` to tell whether class A is a friend of class B?

Sample code:

```
class A {};
class B { friend class A; };
class C { friend class B; };

is_friend<A, B>; // true
is_friend<B, A>; // false
is_friend<B, C>; // true
is_friend<A, C>; // false
```

Comment: I don't know but what would be the point since friend is a hint for compiler? AFAIK, it doesn't generate any code.

Comment: I have implemented something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748131/2565020
To check whether a class is reflectable, instead of checking for the presence of a member/function or creating a flag, I thought it would be more beautiful to check whether the reflectable class is a friend of `reflector`

Comment: @Nighteen May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly) is helpful to some extend.

Comment: Is there any use case for that?

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible.  In your example, nothing in `B` has any access restrictions anyway, so `A`’s friendship has no effect.  Since friendship is neither inherited nor transitive, there’s no way to use a trick like inheriting from the class in question and adding a private member.